# ksh: pattern matching numbers

Tags: regex, ksh

My ksh script's purpose is to delete a set of files from my source directory if it matches certain qualifications.

My file names follow this pattern: `/folder/folder/folder/SrcFiles/195758_load_yield_rates_data_req82565.dat`

What I need is to delete files from the directory for a given user `req99999` and for ids greater than or equal to the parameter. My code and sudo-code is below

```
SrcDir=$1
User=$2
RunId=$3

files=$( ls ${SrcDir}*)

for i in $files ; do
  if [[ $i == *${User}*.dat ]]; then
    echo $i
    fileRunID = ## How do I extract the ids from the file?
    if [[ $fileRunID >= $RunID ]]; then
        echo Delete: echo $i
        rm -f $i
    fi
  fi
done
```

My initial if statement works and I am given the files with the user.  My next plan was to extract the ID from the file then use that in another if statement to match it against the inputed RunID.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out

```
typeset -i RunId=$3

files=$( ls ${SrcDir}*)

for i in $files; do
 if [[ $i == *${User}*.dat ]]; then
    fileRunId=`echo $i | cut -b 32-37`
    typeset -i fileRunId
    if [[ $fileRunId -eq $RunId  ||  $fileRunId -gt $RunId ]]; then
        #echo Delete: $i
        rm -f $i
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Are you using ksh93 ?